# How to lower the number of repaints needed to display a change in graphics

Tags: java, repaint

i want to know if theres some way that i can create an temporary  graphic , to which i can make changes as many times i want , 
and when i feel all changes has been made , repaint the frame only ONCE , to make changes in the graphic visible.

a String analogy would be:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= N; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= N; col++) {
        s.append(String.format("%d %d%s", row, col , delim));
    }
}
System.out.println("created points : \n" + s.toString()); 
// @^^ im only printing the string after all work has been done , instead of at the end of each loop
```

this is what im trying to do :

```
create a 5x5 grid (so it has 25 square sites)
start loop: 
    at random , open each site , paintIt(x,y); // x,y are co-ords of the site opened
    if(connected(topRow,bottomRow))
        break;
    else
        loop again;
    .
    .
    .   
paintIt(int x , int y) :
    if(topRow,bottomRow are connected)
        // this condition means that system "percolates"
        for(some row){
            for(some col){
                if(site(row,col) is open)
                paint the sites LIGHT_BLUE;
                repaint the frame to make changes visible;
                // @^^ this N*N times repaint is what im trying to avoid
            }
        }

    else if(site at (x,y) connected to topRow)
        // this means that the site at (x,y) is "full"
        paint the site LIGHT_BLUE;
        repaint the frame to make changes visible;
    else
        paint the site WHITE;
        repaint the frame to make changes visible;
```

my problem is that , `paintIt()` method gets only the co-ords of the site that has been opened, and when opening ONE particular site makes the whole system "percolate" , 
I have to paint all the opened sites LIGHT_BLUE , and for that , currently i have to run a double for() loop , which checks one by one if each site of the 2D array is
open or not , and sets the paintbrush to hold LIGHT_BLUE accordingly, and then repaints the whole frame , just to change ONE particular site color.

**an image of whats happening :**

```
(4,4)
```

is the site that makes the system Percolate.

[image: an image of whats happening]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a `BufferedImage` the size of your viewport, then get the graphics object from it with `image.getGraphics()` and draw all changes into that graphics object. Then when you've drawn everything you want, draw the `BufferedImage` into the viewports Graphics object.

For additional speed look into `VolatileImage`.